# How do I change the output of this code to only output the first 2 cards?

Tags: python

```
import itertools
import random

vals = ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A']
suits = [
        u"\u2665",  # Hearts
        u"\u2666",  # Diamonds
        u"\u2663",  # Clubs
        u"\u2660",  # Spades
        ]

deck = list(itertools.product(vals, suits))

random.shuffle(deck)

for val, suit in deck:
    print('%s%s' % (val, suit))
```

Comment: Just slice it `deck[:2]`.

Comment: read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/1540468) answer. I'd probably stop short of calling it a duplicate but it should answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools
import random

vals = ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A']
suits = [
        u"\u2665",  # Hearts
        u"\u2666",  # Diamonds
        u"\u2663",  # Clubs
        u"\u2660",  # Spades
        ]

deck = list(itertools.product(vals, suits))

random.shuffle(deck)

for val, suit in deck[:2]:
    print('%s%s' % (val, suit))
```